# Papaya puree types

Tags: puree, ingredients

I have had a problem trying to located good papaya puree. I used to buy it from this company called Dynamic Health, but they changed the type of puree they sell. The two photos below show before and after:

[image][image]

So, you can see, same company, same product, different result. The creamy yellow version on the left is the original. But, if you buy it now, you get the stuff on the right, which is thinner and more syrupy and has a different taste.

Are there different versions of papaya puree that I should be aware of, or is this just a case of a company cutting their product with syrups and flavorants to cheapen it?

Comment: Have you looked at the ingredient list on the label? Packaging requirements in the US & EU would ensure that any additives be included on the label. [This website](https://www.swansonvitamins.com/dynamic-health-papaya-puree-16-fl-oz-liquid) has the US packaging info, which lists "Certified Organic Papaya Puree" as the only ingredient

Answer (score 2):

According to the nutritional labeling information for this product on [a website](https://www.swansonvitamins.com/dynamic-health-papaya-puree-16-fl-oz-liquid) the only ingredient in the current version of the product is "Certified Organic Papaya Puree". I cannot find a similar reference for the older packaging, so I cannot say if there was a change in the ingredient list.

Given that the version you dislike is pure papaya puree, there are a few possible explanations:

- They may have *removed* an additive that provided thickening and a creamier mouth feel.
- The same ingredients with a different processing method may change consistency, color, and taste of the finished product.
- A change in suppliers for their raw papaya product could mean that fruit grown differently, or in a different location, or even a different variety of papaya could explain the difference.
- I noticed that the old label does not say the product is organic, but the new label does. A switch to certified organic may explain a change in raw product-- essentially a possible reason for a change in supplier or raw product.